# Is it possible to create an alternate overlayed background in a textbox frame in beamer?

Tags: beamer, formatting

Here is a sample code. But basically I have a custom background in my presentation, but some part of the text occasionally interfers with the background's color. So I thought I make another overlayed background in a mdframed environment with to work around it. I thought such background would be a smudged background of the original background. Is this feasible in LaTeX or do I have to do this in something like Photoshop?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usebackgroundtemplate{
  \includegraphics[width=6in,height=4in]{Custom BackgroundName}} 
  \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
   So right here is the frame and text with a custom background. Now I want to create a textbox because my textcolor interfers with certain parts of my custom background. So I thought the easiest way out would be to create a smudged overlayered background in a mdframed environcment such as

   \begin{mdframed}

    Text here but in this environment you can read clearer, but the mdframed environment introduces a white background. I want this to be something else, like a smudged background. Also the environment should blend in *smoothly* with the custom background.

    \end{mdframed}


   \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for some semi-transparent blocks, you could do something like

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-grid-100x100bp}}

\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{%
    \pgfsetfillopacity{0.65}%
}{
    \pgfsetfillopacity{1}%
}


\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{Test}
            Bla
    \end{block}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are looking for a way to blur your background image, you are probably better off by using an image manipulation tool like `gimp`.